# ReactJS: how to set a default option for a semantic ui dropdown component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui

I have the following `const` containing my semantic ui dropdown content:

```
const lessonGroup = [
  { key: 'r', value: 'regular', text: 'Regular lesson' },
  { key: 'wp', value: 'wp', text: 'Weak Point lesson' },
  { key: 'wt', value: 'wt', text: 'World Tour lesson' },
]
```

Then the following code:

```
      <Dropdown
        placeholder='Lesson type'
        search
        selection
        options={lessonGroup}
        defaultOption='r'
      />
```

I'm not sure how I can give to the dropdown a default selected option. I played around with `defaultOption` but with no success. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try defaultValue='regular'

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thank you.